# Selecting dropdown option with selenium in Java

Tags: javascript, html, selenium, maven, assert

I'm using selenium to run tests on my front end. I have two drop down menus (whiteplayername and blackplayername) and a submit button. Both must have selected for a submit button (submit-button) to be enabled. When I run the code, it works fine. When I run the test, it is selecting an option from both the drop down menus but it the submit button isn't enabling. I have a feeling that this is because the selection is being made but somehow not being clicked. Here is my test:

```
@Test
@DisplayName("When whitePlayerName and blackPlayerName is selected, submit button is active")
void tesSubmitPage_whenNameIsSelectedFromBothDropDownMenus_submitButtonIsEnabled() {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("material-icons"));
    elements.get(1).click();
    
    WebElement dropdownWhite = driver.findElement(By.id("whiteplayername"));
    Select selectWhite = new Select(dropdownWhite);
    selectWhite.selectByValue("Hywel Griffiths");
    WebElement dropdownBlack = driver.findElement(By.id("blackplayername"));
    Select selectBlack = new Select(dropdownBlack);
    selectBlack.selectByValue("Hywel Griffiths");
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("submit-button")));
    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("submit-button"));

    assertTrue("", button.isEnabled());
}
```

My javascript

```
<script type="module">
    document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;
    const form = document.getElementById("form");
    const submitButton = document.getElementById("submit-button");
    const whitePlayerName = document.getElementById("whiteplayername");
    const blackPlayerName = document.getElementById("blackplayername");
    const firstNameBlack = document.getElementById("firstnameblack");
    const firstNameWhite = document.getElementById("firstnamewhite");
    const lastNameWhite = document.getElementById("lastnamewhite");
    const lastNameBlack = document.getElementById("lastnameblack");

    form.addEventListener('change', () => {
        const whiteNameSelected = whitePlayerName.value;

        // Disable white name inputs if white name is selected in the dropdown
        firstNameWhite.disabled = whiteNameSelected;
        lastNameWhite.disabled = whiteNameSelected;

        // Determine if the white name is either selected or typed in the inputs
        const validWhiteName = whiteNameSelected || (firstNameWhite.value && lastNameWhite.value);

        const blackNameSelected = blackPlayerName.value;

        // Disable black name inputs if black name is selected in the dropdown
        firstNameBlack.disabled = blackNameSelected;
        lastNameBlack.disabled = blackNameSelected;

        // Determine if the black name is either selected or typed in the inputs
        const validBlackName = blackNameSelected || (firstNameBlack.value && lastNameBlack.value);
        
        const submitAvailable = validWhiteName && validBlackName && validSpaces;
        submitButton.disabled = !submitAvailable;

        if (!validWhiteName) {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "Please select at least one  white name.";
        } else if (!validBlackName) {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "Please select at least one  black name.";
        } else if (!validSpaces) {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "Please do not included spaces in the names.";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "";
        }
    });

    form.addEventListener('input', () => {
        const whiteNameSelected = whitePlayerName.value;

        // Disable white name inputs if white name is selected in the dropdown
        firstNameWhite.disabled = whiteNameSelected;
        lastNameWhite.disabled = whiteNameSelected;

        // Determine if the white name is either selected or typed in the inputs
        const validWhiteName = whiteNameSelected || (firstNameWhite.value && lastNameWhite.value);

        const blackNameSelected = blackPlayerName.value;

        // Disable black name inputs if black name is selected in the dropdown
        firstNameBlack.disabled = blackNameSelected;
        lastNameBlack.disabled = blackNameSelected;

        // Determine if the black name is either selected or typed in the inputs
        const validBlackName = blackNameSelected || (firstNameBlack.value && lastNameBlack.value);

        const validSpaces = !lastNameWhite.value.match(/\s+/g) && !firstNameWhite.value.match(/\s+/g) && !lastNameBlack.value.match(/\s+/g) && !firstNameBlack.value.match(/\s+/g);

        const submitAvailable = validWhiteName && validBlackName && validSpaces;
        submitButton.disabled = !submitAvailable;

        if (!validWhiteName) {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "Please select at least one  white name.";
        } else if (!validBlackName) {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "Please select at least one  black name.";
        } else if (!validSpaces) {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "Please do not included spaces in the names.";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("warningtext").textContent = "";
        }
    });
</script>
```

and the thymeleaf html

```
<body style="background-color:rgb(68, 57, 57);">
<div class="warning">
<p id="warningtext"></p><br>
</div>
<div class="topnav">
<a th:href="@{main.html}"><i class="material-icons"
                             style="border:2px;font-size:60px;color:rgb(0, 0, 
0);">arrow_back</i></a>
</div>
<div class="formformat">
<form th:object="${game}" th:action="@{/addgame}" th:method="post" id="form">
    <label for="whiteplayername">Select white player:</label>
    <select name="whiteplayername" id="whiteplayername" th:object="${names}" th:field="${game.whitePlayerName}">
        <option th:value="null" th:selected="${game.name == null}"></option>
        <th:block th:each="name : ${names}">
            <option th:value="${name.name}"
                    th:text="${name.name}"></option>
        </th:block>
    </select>
    <label for="blackplayername">Select black player:</label>
    <select name="blackplayername" id="blackplayername" th:object="${names}" 
th:field="${game.blackPlayerName}">
        <option th:value="null" th:selected="${game.name == null}"></option>
        <th:block th:each="name : ${names}">
            <option th:value="${name.name}"
                    th:text="${name.name}"></option>
        </th:block>
    </select><br><br>
    <label for="firstnamewhite">First name white:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstnamewhite" th:field="*{firstNameWhite}"/>
    <label for="firstnameblack">First name black:</label>
    <input type="text" id="firstnameblack" th:field="*{firstNameBlack}"/><br><br>
    <label for="lastnamewhite">Last name white:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastnamewhite" th:field="*{lastNameWhite}"/>
    <label for="lastnameblack">Last name black:</label>
    <input type="text" id="lastnameblack" th:field="*{lastNameBlack}"/><br><br>
    <label for="date">Date:</label><br>
    <input type="date" id="date" th:field="*{date}">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Move</th>
            <th>White</th>
            <th>Black</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td><input type="text" id="white1" th:field="*{moves}"></td>
            <td><input type="text" id="black1" th:field="*{moves}"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit-button">
</form>
```

I've now changed my test to

```
@Test
@DisplayName("When whitePlayerName and blackPlayerName is selected, submit button is active")
void tesSubmitPage_whenNameIsSelectedFromBothDropDownMenus_submitButtonIsEnabled() throws InterruptedException {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("material-icons"));
    elements.get(1).click();

    JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;

    WebElement whitePlayerNameDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("whiteplayername"));
    WebElement form = driver.findElement(By.id("form"));
    Select whitePlayerNameSelect = new Select(whitePlayerNameDropdown);
    whitePlayerNameSelect.selectByValue("Hywel Griffiths");
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))", form);

    WebElement blackPlayerNameDropdown = driver.findElement(By.id("blackplayername"));
    Select blackPlayerNameSelect = new Select(blackPlayerNameDropdown);
    blackPlayerNameSelect.selectByValue("Hywel Griffiths");
    js.executeScript("arguments[0].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'))", form);

    WebElement button = driver.findElement(By.id("submit-button"));
    assertTrue("", button.isEnabled());
}
```

to trigger the event through a change in the form, but no luck. Just in case it gives anyone any ideas.